# Backslash escape sequences and word boundaries in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

Currently using `re.sub(re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)`

Intended behavior:

```
stringVar = " andrew) "
re.sub(re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar) # Returns " SUB "
```

Unintended behavior:

```
stringVar = "zzzandrew)zzz"
re.sub(re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar) # Returns "zzzSUBzzz"
```

so I'm trying to use word boundaries to fix "zzzandrew)zzz", however my fix breaks my base case.

```
stringVar = " andrew) "
re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar) # Breaks and returns the original stringVar
```

From: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html -> raw strings and use different rules for backslash escape sequences. So what should I do besides re.escape?

Comment: `\b` is a **word boundary**, which is not satisfied by `) `

Comment: ) is explicit in my regex. I'm not trying to match it as a word boundary. But also it is a word boundary: re.sub(r"\bandrew\b", "MASK", "andrew)")

Comment: `zzzandrew)zzz` satisfies your line using `\b%s\b` but ` andrew) ` will not because `\b` doesn't match the parenthesis followed by space. This is why you're not getting a match.

Comment: ??? re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", "zzzandrew)zzz") 
 does not do the sub either. I'm really not following you at all.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, you're right because the left side doesn't match a word boundary. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? This might be the appropriate question to ask. You're not matching `andrew)` because the last character is a `)` and it's not followed by a word character. In the example I gave the forefront is not being match, thus if you drop the first zzz such that you're checking against `andrew)zzz` you'll see it matches.

Comment: ahh I'm seet ctwheels. Thank you. Here's a similar answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/63c96b16-c131-4c93-a67d-1668b51298d4/regex-that-uses-both-word-boundary-as-well-as-escapes-special-characters?forum=regexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python `re` module [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents)

> \b
>
> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. 
>   A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, 
>   so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, 
>   non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is defined as the
>   boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w 
>   and the beginning/end of the string, so the precise set of characters 
>   deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the values of the UNICODE and 
>   LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)',
>   'bar 
>   foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.

In you case the word boundary is recognized as between andrew and ) which is the first non-alphanumeric non-underscore character. The example below illustrates what happens if you include or exclude ')' from the escape.

```
>>> stringVar = " andrew) "
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)
' andrew) '
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("andrew"), "SUB", stringVar)
' SUB) '
>>> stringVar = "zzzandrew)zzz"
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape("andrew"), "SUB", stringVar)
'zzzandrew)zzz'
```

If you have to use the ')' as part of the escape you can use a **positive lookahead assertion** like below which matches if there is a whitespace (\s) or a non-alphanumeric character (\W) after 'andrew)'

```
>>> stringVar = " andrew) "
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\s)' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)
' SUB '
>>> stringVar = "zzzandrew)zzz"
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\s)' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)
'zzzandrew)zzz'
>>> stringVar = " andrew) "
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\W)' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)
' SUB '
>>> stringVar = "zzzandrew)zzz"
>>> re.sub(r'\b%s(?=\W)' % re.escape("andrew)"), "SUB", stringVar)
'zzzandrew)zzz'
```